# Apps started to crash left and right - is it the recent WebView issue?

Tags: xiaomi, crashes, webview, mi

I'm using Xioami MI 9 SE. Over the past day or two, I've started experiencing mysterious crashes on startup with several applications, including a Radio receiver app (local to Israel); Opera occasionally, APKPure; and one or two others.

Now, I noticed other people experiences something similar on their Samsung phones, and also a few new items about a multi-app-crash issue:

[Are your Android apps crashing? You’re not alone.](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-apps-crashing-1210994/)

so I thought my situation may be related. However, the workaround suggested at the link doesn't work for me, since MIUI doesn't even show an "Android System Webview" app.

So, could it be the same issue? ANd - how do I restore my system to working order?

Note: Downloading and installating the latest APKPure version does not seem to resolve the crash.

Comment: Install all available app updates, especially Chrome.

Comment: @Robert: That's a bit of a problem, since I was using APKPure to check what those are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

1. Locate the latest version of the Android System Webview app using any web browser, and using a search engine
2. Download & install the APK. You will find it is actually an update, and a version Android System Webview *is* installed on your phone already; it's just hidden from you somehow.

This worked for me; the apps mentioned above stopped crashing.